# Symfony2 - Form is trying to validate an unused field

Tags: php, symfony

So, I have a form that allows a user to update their profile details (name, email etc etc)

The form displays correctly, using a Form Type (UserType) which points to the User Entity. UserType builds the form with the username, email and then extends to ProfileType - another Form Type that includes their real name, address etc.

As I mentioned, the form displays on the page correctly.

Now, In my validation.yml file I am point to both User and Profile entities, and for User I am defining 3 validation rules, for username, email and password. For Profile, I am defining rules for name and company name. All rules has NotBlank, email also has checks to make sure it is valid and password has max and min length defined.

Now, The Password rules were added recently. Previously, this form worked fine, no issues.

Adding the password rules in, when the form is submitted, it tries to check against this validation rule, but there is no password field rendered on the page, or even mentioned in the Form Type, UserType.

Surely, if I do not use an input, it shouldn't check for it against the validation rules?

Code below:

Validation.yml

```
DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\User\Profile:
properties:
    name:
        - NotBlank: ~
    pubName:
        - NotBlank: ~

DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\User\User:
    properties:
        username:
            - NotBlank:
                message: Username cannot be blank.
        email:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.
                checkMX: true
        password:
            - MaxLength: { limit: 20, message: "Your password must not exceed {{ limit }} characters." }
            - MinLength: { limit: 4, message: "Your password must have at least {{ limit }} characters." }
            - NotBlank: ~
```

UserType.php

```
namespace DEMO\DemoBundle\Form\Type\User;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackValidator;

use DEMO\DemoBundle\Form\Type\User\ProfileType;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('username');
        $builder->add('email');
        $builder->add('profile', new ProfileType());
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\User\User',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

ProfileType.php

```
namespace DEMO\DemoBundle\Form\Type\User;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormError;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackValidator;

class ProfileType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
        $builder->add('companyName', null, array('label' => 'Company Name'));
        $builder->add('address1', null, array('label' => 'Address 1'));
        $builder->add('address2', null, array('label' => 'Address 2'));
        $builder->add('city');
        $builder->add('county');
        $builder->add('postcode');
        $builder->add('telephone');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'DEMO\DemoBundle\Entity\User\Profile',
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'profile';
    }
}
```

DashboardController.php

```
public function profileAction(Request $request)
    {

        $user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $user);

        if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
            $form->bindRequest($request);

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                // Get $_POST data and submit to DB
                $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
                $em->persist($user);
                $em->flush();

                // Set "success" flash notification
                $this->get('session')->setFlash('success', 'Profile saved.');
            }

        }

        $breadcrumbs = $this->get("white_october_breadcrumbs");
        $breadcrumbs->addItem("Home", $this->get("router")->generate("shop"));
        $breadcrumbs->addItem("My Account", $this->get("router")->generate("shop"));
        $breadcrumbs->addItem("My Profile", $this->get("router")->generate("shop"));

        return $this->render('DEMODemoBundle:User\Dashboard:profile.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
    }
```

profile.html.twig

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span12">
            {% form_theme form 'DEMODemoBundle:User\\Form:fields.html.twig' %}

            {{ form_errors(form) }}

            <form action="{{ path('tk_update_profile') }}" class="form-horizontal" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }} novalidate="novalidate">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Your Details</legend>
                    {{ form_row(form.username) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.name) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.email) }}
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Company Details</legend>
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.companyName) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.address1) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.address2) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.city) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.county) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.postcode) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.profile.telephone) }}
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        {{ form_rest(form) }}
                        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save" />
                        <input class="btn-warning" type="reset" value="Reset">
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When filling in the form, backed by a User entity, the system will attempt to create a new User object and validate every rule which belongs to the entity.
What you need are validation groups, where you basically say 'just check for the constraints that apply when I'm doing the "edit" operation'.

You can check it out here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validation-groups